# Delete specified value from all cell without breaking document formatting

Tags: excel, formatting, cell, vba

I need to delete a group of specified numbers from a specified cell without losing the actual document format. This group of numbers contains, like, 100 numbers but for simplicity's sake I'm showing just a couple of chars.

I've tried the method `ClearContents` of the object `Range` but i got this "runtime error 1004". How do I fix this?

```
Sub deleteval()

Dim delete
delete = Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g")

Dim i As Long, j As Long

Dim isThere As Boolean

For i = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    For j = LBound(delete) To UBound(delete)
        If StrComp(Range("A" & i), delete(j), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            isThere = True
        End If
    Next j
    If isThere Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i).delete shift:=xlUp
    End If
    isThere = False
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, shoud work

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i).Select
Selection.ClearContents
```

A little tips:
Record a macro, simulte your action, stop macro recorder, then see the code automatically produced.

tested this and clearcontents works as expected! (added error handling)

```
Sub deleteval()
On Error GoTo errdeleteval
Dim delete
delete = Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g")

Dim i As Long, j As Long

Dim isThere As Boolean

For i = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    For j = LBound(delete) To UBound(delete)
        If StrComp(Range("A" & i), delete(j), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            isThere = True
        End If
    Next j
    If isThere Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("A9" & i).ClearContents
    End If
    isThere = False
Next i

On Error GoTo 0
Exit Sub
errdeleteval:
Debug.Print Err.Description & " (A" & i & ") "

End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks for ur answer! It works perfectly :). Although, u wrote : `ActiveSheet.Range("A9" & i).ClearContents`

But this doesn't match with the previous column, so i changed "A9" to "A" and everything runs smooth. Again, thanks for ur time :))